# How to include password in jupyter cell while installing a package from git

Tags: git, azure-devops, pip, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to pip install in jupyter notebook using the code below

```
%pip install git+https://company-projects@dev.azure.com/company-projects/company/_git/coolpkg
```

and I get the below message as the repo is password protected. I know the password but I am not sure how to include that in the command above.
Please let me know thanks.

```
........
........
Password for 'https://company-projects@dev.azure.com':
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way, you can go about this after numerous tries, just need to add token in the url.

```
%pip install git+https://<token>@dev.azure.com/company-projects/company/_git/coolpkg
```